# How can I convert this mysql query into postgres 9.4

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.4

First off I have the same table names,columns and data in both databases (MySQL and Postgres) the query that I use for MySQL 5.6.24 that works it this

```
select *,abs(longitudes - -81.4563009)+abs(latitudes-28.11657) as LowestNum 
from zips group by LowestNum limit 1
```

I'm basically trying to get the nearest location given a latitude and longitude when I put that same query into postgres 9.4 I get an error that states

```
ERROR: column "zips.zip" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 8
```

I then change things around and do this

```
select *, abs(longitudes - -81.3952524)+abs(latitudes-28.4583868) as   
LowestNum from zips group by LowestNum,zips.zip limit 1
```

and I get this error

```
ERROR: column "zips.ziptype" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 8
```

I am new at postgres but been looking at the documentation and searching around and nothing works any suggestions.

Comment: You want the lowest num (lowestNum) by zip code ?

Comment: I want the lowestNum by latitude and longitude on the last query I put zips.zip because that error showed up for that column.

Comment: You will need either `min(LowestNum)` or `order by LowestNum limit 1` to tell PostgreSQL that you want the lowest value. Furthermore, you should have a look at the tutoral that covers aggregate functions like `min` in PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-agg.html

Comment: The `order by LowestNumb limit 1` is missing the `ascending`.

Comment: Hmmm, are you really sure, your original query works? How does MySQL know that you are not looking for the _maximum_?

Comment: @hagello: MySQL actually doesn't. It simply returns a random value (they call it an *indeterminate*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
select *, abs(longitudes - -81.4563009)+abs(latitudes-28.11657) as LowestNum 
from zips 
order by LowestNum ascending 
limit 1
```

Sorry, I have no PostgreSQL instance to test it.

`order by [..] ascending/descending limit 1` is a common way of avoiding `min` and `max` and the difficulties that they entail when you have more than one result column (`group by`, joins).

Comment: A historical note: In PostgreSQL versions <= 8.?, the code for handling aggregate functions like `min` or `max` was somewhat dumb. You really had to use `order by ... limit 1` to make it use indices.

Comment: Other possible solutions are to use `distinct on ()` if more than one row is expected or the when ANSI SQL is required a window function